# Digital Tutors supply the programs needed for the tasks?

Tags: java

Does Digital tutors supply the programs needed for the tasks or do they expect you to have it? Thanks from a Nub

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not even remotely about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by programs if you mean 3dmax , maya , houdini ,zbrush  , .. so the answer is no and you have to buy them yourself but if you mean models and scenes that are used during training yes they are in the package

Answer (score 0):

Have no clue what 'Digital tutors' is, but you can always download `blender` or a similar modeling software for free. Do some 'Google'ing or check out the FAQ area of that website.